# Trying to navigate to bottomNavScreen when the user is logged in

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to navigate to BottomNavbar screen when the user is logged in now, I have created user manually in firebase (as the client request) I did everything correctly, but it's stuck on splash screen and show a progress bar only and didn't navigate to anyScreen here is my code.

```
class LoginCubit extends Cubit<LoginState> {
final FirebaseAuthService _authService;
LoginCubit(this._authService) : super(LoginInitial());

Future<void> loginWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
emit(LoginLoading());
try {
  UserCredential userCredential =
      await _authService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  emit(LoginSuccess(userCredential.user!));
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  print('Error Code: ${e.code}');
  print('Error Message: ${e.message}');
  switch (e.code) {
    case 'user-not-found':
      emit(LoginFailure('No user found for that email.'));
      break;
    case 'wrong-password':
      emit(LoginFailure('Wrong password provided for that user.'));
      break;
    default:
      emit(LoginFailure(e.message ?? 'An unknown error occurred.'));
  }
}
}

Future<void> checkAuthenticationStatus() async {
emit(LoginLoading());
try {
  var user = _authService.getCurrentUser();
  if (user != null) {
    emit(LoginSuccess(user));
  } else {
    emit(
        LoginInitial()); // Emitting a state when the user is not authenticated
  }
} catch (e) {
  emit(LoginFailure(e.toString()));
}
}
}
```

splash screen

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocListener<LoginCubit, LoginState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state is LoginSuccess) {
      context.goNamed(AppRoutes.bottomNavBarRoute);
    } else if (state is LoginFailure) {
      context.goNamed(AppRoutes.loginRoute);
    }
  },
  child: const Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

firebase_auth

```
class FirebaseAuthService {
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

User? getCurrentUser() {
return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
}

Future<UserCredential> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
String email, String password) async {
return await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email, password: password);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two things for now. I assume this is all the code in our splash screen. I belelive you should call the function `checkAuthenticationStatus`
after the build function. And second that perhaps you have already somewhere that function is being called and still not navigating.  Using a dfifferent navigation method might change the outcome of the app.